# Autofac Dependency Injection in Azure Function

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, azure-functions

I am trying to implement DI using Autofac IOC in Azure function.
I need to build the container, but not sure where to put the code to build the container

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think for now you would need to do something ugly like:

```cs
public static string MyAwesomeFunction(string message)
{
    if (MyService == null)
    {
        var instantiator = Initialize();
        MyService = instantiator.Resolve<IService>();
    }

    return MyService.Hello(message);
}

private static IService MyService = null;

private static IContainer Initialize()
{
    // Do your IoC magic here
}
```

Comment: This is the same (albeit dirty feeling) technique that I use right now. Not sure if there's any other option until Functions provides an extensibility point to inject your own values

Comment: DI is now supported out of the box by Azure Functions v2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Answer (score 12):

I did write a blog entry for doing dependency injection with Autofac in Azure Functions. Have a look here:
[Azure Function Dependency Injection with AutoFac: Autofac on Functions](http://codingsoul.de/2018/01/19/azure-function-dependency-injection-with-autofac/)

It follows a similar approach like the one by [Boris Wilhelms](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-proper-dependency-injection/). 
Another implementation based on Boris' approach can be found on github: [autofac dependency injection](https://github.com/introtocomputerscience/azure-function-autofac-dependency-injection)

-- update ---

With Azure Function v2 it is possible to create nuget packages based on .net standard. Have a look onto
[Azure Functions Dependency Injection with Autofac: Autofac on Functions nuget Package](http://codingsoul.de/2018/06/12/azure-functions-dependency-injection-autofac-on-functions-nuget-package/)

Comment: Hi Holger, can you tell me, what namespace/library is IObjectResolver  from?

Comment: Hi Scott, it's an own implementation. What you are heading for?

Answer (score 4):

While Azure Functions does not support DI out of the box, it is possible to add this via the new Extension API. You can register the container using an IExtensionConfigProvider implementation. You can find a full example DI solution in Azure here https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-proper-dependency-injection/.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Functions doesn't support dependency injection yet. Follow this issue for the feature request 
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/299

Comment: Azure Functions 2.x now supports .NET Core Dependency Injection:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

I've written a different answer to the main question, with a different solution, totally tied to the main question.

Previous solutions were either manually initializing a DI or using the decorator way of doing it. My idea was to tie the DI to the Functions Builder in the same way we do with aspnet, without decorators.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a custom [inject] attribute. See example here https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/azure-functions-proper-dependency-injection/