# Dependency Injection for Azure Functions V1 DI

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have a new issue regarding the *dependency injection in azure **function v1***.

*Actual situation:*

I have an azure **function V1** `http triggered` in which I want to reference my business services the way I can use my services without reinventing the wheel.
I searched on the internet and I found this interesting [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection)  from Microsoft.

However, it seems like it only works with **azure function v2** (.net core) because whenever I try to install the  `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions`, I always get the following error :

> NU1107    Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.
>   Install/reference Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.5 directly to project
>   FunctionApp2365431 to resolve this issue.  FunctionApp2365431 ->
>   Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions 1.0.0 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
>   (>= 3.0.5)  FunctionApp2365431 -> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.28
>   -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.4.0)

Following, a comparison between the dlls of two project (one in .net core (in which i could implement DI) and the other in Net framework 461)

[image: Comparison]

You can see that versions are different, the .net core **V2 azure function is 3.5** and the **V1 is 2.2**

I tried to **reference/install manually** the package version as asked in the error, and I was asked to update NewtonSoft.Json package too, I did that too, and I could after that force the installation of the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions` **BUT,** it broke the project and I **couldn’t stop getting errors**.

Here is the build result after doing the steps mentioned above:

[image: Build errors]

My question here is, 
How can I setup **DI in Net framework project eg. For Azure functions V1**?

Then, Why there **is only documentation for azure function V2 to setup DI**?

Are V1 deprecated or is Microsoft not supporting the V1 azure functions anymore?Because this is weird!

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT** :
My question is not a duplicate of this [StackOverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912224/di-in-azure-functions) because it's a complicated way and outdated comparing to the solution that Microsoft is providing for v2 azure functions.

I also watched this interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsNSf5TG4yc) (still didn't test it), and the only problem here is that i want to use something provided by Microsoft (official) as for az func v2, and not the package that he has developed.

Comment: Functions v1 is not deprecated, they are still being fully supported but most (or even all?) new features will only go into v2. DI is afaik one of those cases.

Comment: "new features will only go into v2" did Microsoft confirm this ? because if it's true, i think that it's an implicit invitation from Microsoft to use V2 Functions instead of the V1...

Comment: "There are two major versions of the Azure Functions runtime: 1.x and 2.x. The current version where new feature work and improvements are being made is 2.x, though both are supported for production scenarios. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions

Answer (score 1):

As @silent mentioned in his comment,

Here is the response from Microsoft

> Regarding to your query , here is the response from Azure Function
>   prod team :
>
> 1. There is no plan to abandon Azure function V1 , but Azure function V2 is recommended as it will get more new features in the future .
> 2. For now , DI feature is supported by Azure function V2 only , if you need this feature , maybe migrating your app from V1 to V2 will be
>      a good idea ,and this doc will be helpful :
>      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#migrating-from-1x-to-2x

So the unique way to do it until now is to follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsNSf5TG4yc) which is about implementing **DI in Azure function V1** using `AzureFunctions.Autofac` package.

HK,